# How do I create a single Docker container (Node, Python, FFMPEG)?

Tags: python, express, docker

My eventual goal is to have a container that can run my Express server. The server uses PyShell to run Python to analyze video with FFMPEG. I have already built the server and it works well. 
The problem is, I am trying to create a Docker container that can run this 3 part operation, and it seems that multi-stage building might be the best way to do this. So, the players involved:
Node (express)
Python
FFMPEG

Before I attempt to add FFMPEG into the container, I'm trying to simply get Node and Python running in a multistage build container.

My docker file so far:

---

FROM node:8 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

FROM python:latest

COPY --from=builder . .

CMD ["node", "server.js"]

---

when run with Docker, this results in:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

I apologize if this is a really amateur question. From what I understand, most people use multistage builds to slim down their containers, but it seems like it should be really easy to build my dream 3 part container. 
Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Looks to me like you have not given it the correct path to you file

Comment: thanks for replying! Do you mean I specified a path incorrectly in the Docker file?

Comment: I believe he means that docker is having trouble finding server.js. Are you in the correct directory when you run the docker build command such that server.js is pulled in to /usr/src/app?

Comment: Yes. The Dockerfile is in the same directory as server.js. The build executes without any errors, but the error comes up when I'm attempting to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Used alpine to install python, node, and ffmpeg during build process.